# Date Format Identification in Nodejs , Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have to find the format of date coming from various data sources. What is the best way to find the format of date considering date , month and year can be in any order .

I need to determine the format by analysing some 10 random records from the table.

```
function isValidDate(str) {
    var d = moment(str,moment.ISO_8601);             
    if (d == null || !d.isValid()) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    match = ['YYYY-MM-DD','D/M/YYYY','DD/MM/YYYY','D/M/YY','DD/MM/YY','D-M-YYYY','DD-MM-YYYY','D-M-YY','DD-MM-YY','YYYY-MM-DD','YYYY-DD-MM',"MMMM D,YYYY","MMM Do,YYYY"] ;

    for(let i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        if(str.indexOf(d.format(match[i])) >= 0 ) 
        {
            return match[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible for example you can not differentiate between `MM-DD-YYYY` and `DD-MM-YYYY` all the time.

Comment: yeah that's true in this case .Is there any method you can suggest for this.

Comment: you still don't understand. `03-04-1970` is it `3rd of April` or `4th of March`? if you cannot distinguish then how your code will? you need to think about your requirements again and put some constraints.

Comment: maybe use other records to find which is the month and day, number greater than 12 is day for sure

Comment: are you trying to train your model with some random formats in `ML`? all the data in array will be of same format?

Comment: No ML here . All I am doing is finding the datatype (string , date , number) of the column and displaying it in user interface of an application. For date alone I need to display the format also . Hope I put things clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this WAY..
This will help you...

providing date to moment will validate it, no need to pass the date Format.

```
var date = moment("2016-10-19");
```

And then

```
date.isValid()
```

gives desired result.